# Leaflet popup misaligned when loading content dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, popup, alignment, leaflet

I've got a problem of popup misalignment when its content is dynamically loaded, like this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7616xqbb/2/

Using Leaflet 0.7.2 :

```
var new_marker = L.marker([lat, lon])
        .bindPopup("<div id='popupcontent'></div>", {maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 300})
        .on('click', function(e){
            $.post("updatecontent.php", {lat: lat, lon: lon},
            function(data) {
                $('#popupcontent').html(data);
            });
        });

map.addLayer(new_marker, true);
```

where updatecontent.php shows a set of images.

I first had troubles making the size of the popup to adapt to its content. This piece of CSS does the trick:

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
     width:auto !important;
     height:auto !important;
}
```

but the popup shifts when it opens...

Any idea? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the popup to your marker after having set the content of the popup

```
var popup = new L.Popup();

marker.addTo(map);

marker.on('click', function(e) { 
    popup.setContent('Hello world');
    marker.bindPopup(popup);
    marker.openPopup();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/79w2mtod/

Comment: Yes, but that is not loading dynamically the content. I need to set the result of a $.post request into the popup.

Comment: Just put the setContent, bindPopup, openPopup in the callback of your $.post.

Answer (score 0):

To align the bindPopup text do as follows

```
marker.bindPopup('<div id="popupcontent" class="centerClass"></div>');
```

CSS

```
.centerClass{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const DefaultIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: ....,
  shadowUrl: ....,
  popupAnchor: [x, y] // point from which the popup should open relative to
});
```

try to aligne it based on x and y and that's it, I hope you find it useful.